# Finding score of node based on average of child node scores for d3 packed circle viz

Tags: javascript, d3.js, callback, circle-pack

I'm trying to build a view based on the zoomable packed circle visualization per http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535 and I'm trying to have each container parent's color be based on the average of its child nodes' scores.

In the above, I think I ahve figured I need to change the .style in:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; })
  .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });
```

My problem is that I'm not overly familiar with whether such a recursion might be achieved in d3. I'd prefer it to be in-line but my coding is not the best. I suspect that I might need to write a separate function and call it within the block, something akin to:

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return d.children ? color(calculatingFn(d)) : d.score; })
```

I guess the question really is: what should calculatingFn(d) look like (or any other more elegant solution)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you would want to do this in a preprocessing step where you traverse the tree from the leafs and "bubble up" the colours. The way it's done at the moment traverses the tree top-down so you won't get all the information you need to colour a node.

Comment: I thought this was able to be performed at execution of color selection. I guess I could add values to each parent in pre-calculated fashion, but that seems rather ugly; I would have thought this could be achieved by walking the tree and calculating per node (down through it's children) somehow.

Comment: You would have to do the same thing, except for every subtree that you're considering. Amounts to the same in the end, except much less efficient.

Comment: Um, any advice on this preprocessing step? I assume this will be similar to your accumulate() func you've described elsewhere, but I'm pretty sure I'm going to have to end up with 2 new attributes to achieve a weighted average (sum of ".score * .value" and sum of ".value" for the children of each node). I week has shown that I'm not really strong enough in JS/D3 coding to achieve that just yet (I don't seem to be able to create the relevant attributes for the node?)

Comment: You'd be creating a recursive function that, given a node, returns the (average) values/scores below this node. If it's a leaf node, you simply return the value, else make the recursive call for each of the child nodes and combine the results of those calls.

Comment: I've tried the below for the attributes separately (since it's a weighted avg):

  `function getScoreTotal(node) {
    if(!node.children) {
        return (node.score * node.total);
    }
    var scoreTotal = 0;
    node.children.forEach(function(d) {
        scoreTotal +=  getScoreTotal(d);
    }) 
    return scoreTotal;
  }
  
  function getValueTotal(node) {
    if(!node.children) {
        return node.value;
    }
    var valueTotal = 0;
    node.children.forEach(function(d) {
        valueTotal +=  getValueTotal(d);
    }) 
    return valueTotal;
  }`

Can't get them to stick

Comment: Well you're not actually assigning any attributes in your code. You'd need to call that function for each node and assign the return value to an attribute.